# x axis labels not properly rotating when plotting multiple graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple graphs, using R. Following is the graph that I have tried

```
p<-ggplot(data = banking_data, aes(x = education, fill = y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
# Vertical rotation of x axis text
p +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=1))

q<-ggplot(data = banking_data, aes(x = job, fill = y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
# Vertical rotation of x axis text
q +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
grid.arrange(p,q)
```

When graphs are plotted, here is how it shows

[image]

The x axis labels do not properly rotate.
If individual graphs are plotted then everything works smoothly.
Can someone kindly help to fix this

Below is my R version details

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with `mtcars` and some `geom_bar`s. I'm on R-4.0.2, ggplot2-3.3.0, perhaps you have an older version?

Comment: HI... I edited my R version. but may be my ggplot versions gowngraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you did not re-assign the second and 4th lines to p and q, respectively. Would that solve your problem?

```r
library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = disp)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
# Vertical rotation of x axis text
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=1))

q<-ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
# Vertical rotation of x axis text
q <- q +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
grid.arrange(p,q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>